# Upgrade CordovaWebView

Tags: android, cordova

I tried to update an old project created with cordova , everything works except CordovaWebView. how can I solve the following errors?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawing);
    FrameLayout MainFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.MainFrame);
    MainFrame.addView(appView.getRootView(), 0);

    appView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    appView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    appView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "Drawing");
    appView.setWebViewClient(new syWebViewClient(this, appView));




    loadUrl(launchUrl);
   }
```

None of appView method is recognized.